# TikZ's fixed point arithmetic not happy with arrows.meta

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, fp

When I try to combine using the features of `arrows.meta` in a context where I'm also using `fixed point arithmetic`, I'm getting an error message.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
                    my arrow/.style={arrows={-Stealth[scale=1.5]}},
                    fixed point arithmetic,
                    ]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (60:3in);
  \draw[my arrow] (A) --  (B);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the error message:

```
! FP error: Illegal character \pgfarrowlength  found in float number!.
\FP@errmessage #1->\errmessage {FP error: #1!}

l.18   \draw[my arrow] (A) --  (B);

?
```

How do I work around this?

Comment: Do you need `fixed point arithmetic` exactly for arrows or not?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I do not need `fixed point arithmetic` for arrows at all.  But I do use it extensively for calculating `node` positions and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems suggesting that `fixed point arithmetic` messes up the `arrows.meta` internal computations.

The natural workaround is to put within a `scope` environment all material that needs to be processed with `fixedpointarithmetic` and to keep code depicting arrows outside.

An example:

```
\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
                    my arrow/.style={arrows={-Stealth[scale=1.5]}},
                    ]
  \begin{scope}[fixed point arithmetic]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (60:3in);

  % a few operations here
  \draw (A) parabola ($(B)-(.25,.45)$);
  \draw ($(B)-(.25,.45)$) parabola (A);
  \end{scope}

  % arrows outside the "dangerous" environment
  \draw[my arrow] (A) --  (B);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]